# PTIJ: Love Shalom and Kill Shalom?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The mishna says in pirkei avos:

> הוי מתלמידיו של אהרן, אוהב שלום ורודף שלום
>
> We should be like the students of Ahron - we should love Shalom, and
> chase to kill Shalom.

How is this  possible in practice? The minute someone sees you being rodef shalom they'll either injury you or kill you!
Furthermore, how is it possible to love shalom but also want to kill shalom?
How can I do both at the same time?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Rodef is not only used to mean chasing someone to murder them it is also used to refer to chasing them for something that is not a stira to loving them.

Comment: @user6591 way to ruin perfectly good Purim Torah.

Comment: Of course that's the point of the purim joke.

Comment: It's a love-hate relationship ;-)

Comment: @YeZ why is that ruining it?

Comment: You should love him to death. What’s the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aharon, as the first Kohen, was the quintessential representative of what it means to be a Kohen.

We see ([Bamidbar 25:11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9953#v=11)-12) that Pinchas was awarded with becoming a Kohen for being קנא את קנאתי - taking up My (Hashem's) zealotry.  So Kehuna fits with taking up Hashem's zealotry.  As the prime alpha Kohen, Aharon certainly had this attribute.

Aharon chased Shalom even though he loved Shalom.  Had he despised Shalom, then he wouldn't have been chasing Shalom for Hashem's zealotry - it would have been his own. It is only by loving Shalom that you can then chase him and be fulfilling the lofty level of taking up Hashem's zealotry.

Alternatively, it refers to chasing [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) in the race for more reputation points. You should love him for all his contributions to the site, and chase after him in pursuit of more repuation.  [Gershon Gold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/200/gershon-gold) is the only known violator of this precept.

Comment: After a year and a half of inactivity, Alex now finally trails two people. I guess he's a Baal Teshuva.

Answer (score 1):

אוהב שלום ורודף שלום are the names of two Conservative shuls. These shuls learned how to manage their finances from another shul named "B'nai Aharon" which was an Orthodox shul in the early 1900's. Thus, the beginning of the phrase is הוי מתלמידיו של אהרן
Be like the students of "Aharon".

Comment: So who am I supposed to kill?

Comment: @Nafkamina - You don't kill anyone. That's my point. It's a different translation. It's saying that you should learn to manage finances like these other 2 Conserv. shuls do.