# PTIJ: Have we been davening for Shalom to reach 100 K?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

At the end of every Amidah and Kaddish (except the "half" Kaddish) we say:

...

> יעשה שלום עלינו
>
> [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) should be over us.

Well, it seems that [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) has passed the [100K reputation mark](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/meya-alafim-mi-yodeya-shalom-yodeya?cb=1). He's #2 on the all-time reputation list. But, he exceeds #3 by about 21K points - a large enough number that I don't think anyone will knock him out of the #2 spot.

I think that we davened to G-d that he gets to this point; perhaps not? Is there any support to this idea? And, now that he has achieved this goal, I think G-d has assured his blessing, already upon him. Do we need to daven for him, still?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: We also ask the angels which accompany us on Friday night that Shalom be over us in reputation: 'שלום עליכם, מלאכי השרת וגו

Comment: Well at the very least, Gershon Gold needs to keep davening for this...

Comment: @ezra Not quite. It says עליכם - Shalom is over the angels; not us. Hmm, it's getting weird and freaky %-}

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't understand. Gershon is already in 1st place.

Comment: @DanF SO SHOULDN'T HE BE DAVENING THAT SHALOM WILL BE OVER HIM IN REPUTATION!?

Comment: Based on your title of "PTIJ: Have we been davening for Shalom to be the first to reach 100 K?", I think that would be pure Tefillas Shav. Gershon was the first, how could we daven for Shalom to be first?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55833/4794

Answer (score 4):

"Shalom Shalom, la-rachok ve-lakarov." Whether you're nowhere near 100k points or almost there, it's all good.

Comment: I think there's some sort of chiyuv to upvote your answer to the question about you getting more reputation points...

Comment: Very good! Look who's getting further away from 100K. (Hey! that rhymes!)

Answer (score 2):

There is a source in [Tehillim](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2634.htm) for this.

> .סוּר מֵרָע, וַעֲשֵׂה-טוֹב;    בַּקֵּשׁ שָׁלוֹם וְרָדְפֵהוּ
>
> He departs from bad questions, and makes good answers; seek out [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) and pursue him.

We like Shalom's answers. How else did he get so much reputation? Therefore, we daven that he be above in reputation over all Israel, so that his great answers on Mi Yodeya don't cease.

By the way, since you might be looking for him, since you have to "pursue him", I'd recommend not looking in Meshech or the tents of Kedar, because he won't be there. ([Tehillim 120:5-7](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26c0.htm))

> .אוֹיָה-לִי, כִּי-גַרְתִּי מֶשֶׁךְ;    שָׁכַנְתִּי, עִם-אָהֳלֵי קֵדָר. רַבַּת, שָׁכְנָה-לָּהּ נַפְשִׁי--    עִם, שׂוֹנֵא שָׁלוֹם. אֲנִי-שָׁלוֹם, וְכִי אֲדַבֵּר;    הֵמָּה, לַמִּלְחָמָה
>
> Woe is me, that I live in Meshech, that I dwell with the tents of Kedar! For too long has my soul lived with those who hate Shalom. I am for Shalom, but when  I speak of him, they are for war.

Comment: The only problem I see with this answer is that we have to chase after Shalom. I guess others have been doing this. He's too fast for us.